# Apache solr search part of the word

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, django-search-lucene

I'm using apache solr search engine for indexing my website database..

I'm using django+http://haystacksearch.org/

So let's say I have document that have word "Chicken"

When I search for "chicken" - solr can find this document

But When I search "chick" - it does not find anything..

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Note: The following solution is Solr 1.4 *(and above)* specific!**

For more flexibility, I would recommend indexing your data with the [NGramTokenizerFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizerFactory.html) to do complete front and back wildcard searches. If you just want to search for substrings at the beginning or end of the string, consider using the [EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory.html).

Here's a drop in replacement of the text field type which would accomodate your need:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" >
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: solr 1.5 - is this development version ? (not released ?)

Comment: is there solution like this for 1.4 ?

Comment: That's really useful... Personally i think i'd create a new fieldtype like the above.. but called ntext or something.. just so you don't mess with the original text fieldtype.

Comment: The NGramTokenizerFactory works great for me (even on 1.3 version)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find all words that start with chick, search for chick*.

Comment: I am not able to use \*chick\*? is it possible?

Comment: @soundar, That's a **bad** chick ;) You can't have * infront of the search keyword, Lucene does not support that.

Answer (score 4):

When I've used

```
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
```

for making wildcard search from Brian's answer, Solr indexing time dramaticly increased. In more than 20 times!
The other decision of wildcard searching problem I found here:

http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/

You need just add filter

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
```

(default tokenizer - solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory in index block of FieldType). For me result was the same with less system costs.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, if you are having trouble with a small set of words, would be to use the solr.SynonymFilterFactory

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

You just have to maintain a simple text file that contains synonyms:

```
chick peep chicken
dawg hound dog
moggie puss kitten cat
```

Plurals should take care of themselves with other filters.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed any configuration. I am just using star in front and in the back of my searchString: *chicke * (without white space at the end -> it's because of SO formatting word as italic if you use * at the beginning and at the end)