# Solr WildCard Search Issue

Tags: solr

I am facing an issue in the solr search....The wild card search seems to be working fine but there are issues when i am trying to find terms within another word.....For example: "rtebiggestBug", when i search for biggest , it doesn't give any results.I have the following entries made in the schema.xml file

```xml
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
     <!--   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>-->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <!--   <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/> -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" preserveOriginal="1"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <!-- <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>-->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!--  <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>-->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Another issue is,it does not find strings at the end of the word.  Example: I searched on “bug” and found bugs and not the word "samplebug".

It would be really helpful if you could help me on this issue..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO question on Solr wildcarding, with additional tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974394/apache-solr-search-part-of-the-word/1976045#1976045

Answer (score 4):

By default Solr does not support left truncation, like searches for `*bug` to find `samplebug`.

Use the `solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` in order to reverse the term and index the therm in an revered way, like  `gubelpmas`. [solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory)

Here is an tutorial: http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query parser is not able to handle leading wildcard searches.

What query parser are you using ?

The Extended dismax query parser supports searches with leading wildcards. you want to check for it.