# Solr - Search by the first part of text

Tags: sql, solr, wildcard

i am new on Solr theme.
I need to know how I can search records at solr but using the field title where start with  two words and then wilcard. For example when i search on SQL command I can put like "Who is %".

How i can search by the first part of text and wildcard?

I have tested different things but nothing worked. This way not work:
http//www.domain.com:8080/solr/select?q=title:"Who is *"

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268480/326543) help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use wildcards for phrases. You can instead use the [prefix query parser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/PrefixQParserPlugin.html) for your fields of `string` type:

```
http//www.domain.com:8080/solr/select?q={!prefix f=title}Who is
```

Note, that this solution is case-sensitive, so if you want to search for "who is", you should lower-case your fields, when you add documents to Solr and do lower-casing of the query in your program as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make Solr believe that your phrase is only a word.

If you index that with a filter like this `solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\s+)` and then make sure to apply the same regex to your query *before* sending it to solr, this will do the trick.

HAve a look at this link for more details:http://pietervogelaar.nl/solr-3-5-wildcard-search-as-sql-like/

please also keep this known issue in mind:  http://bensch.be/the-solr-wildcard-problem-and-multiterm-solution