# DSE: Wildcard searches

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am currently attempting to do a wildcard search and edited my schema file accordingly using the link [here](https://risdenk.github.io/2018/10/25/apache-solr-leading-wildcard-queries-reversedwildcardfilterfactory.html), I have also read up the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267895/solr-wildcard-searching) and attempted to do the necessary changes for SOLR and queried using `token(hel*o)` but failed to accomplish the desired search results. Hence, I would like to ask if my approach for wildcard searches is incorrect? As I noticed that regular expressions can be searched using `tokenRegex(...)` without the need of changing the schema.

===Update===

```
DSE Version : 6.7.2
Execution code : g.V().hasLabel("person_node").has("name", "Jo*")

Schema Used
----------------
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextWildcard">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I would like to achieve a normal wildcard query where * means that there can be many matches of non-space characters e.g Hel*o will be able to match Hello, Heleawo or Helzzzzo.

Additionally, it will also work with ? where it matches only one non-space character e.g Hel?o will match Helzo and not Helzzzo.

Comment: What DSE version is used, and how do you execute queries. What is the schema that you created, and most important - what do you want to achieve - something like SQL's 'LIKE' operation?

Comment: @AlexOtt I have updated the post and I hope it answers your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok - you're not using correct graph operation. To perform what you want you need following:

[Create search index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createIndexes.html) on given property with:

```
schema.vertexLabel('person_node').index('searchname').search().by('name').asString().add()
```

[Perform search](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/useSearchIndexes.html#useSearchIndexes__regex-String) with:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person_node").has("name", regex("Jo*"))
```

Comment: I have attempted the solution presented but it is still analyzing it in terms of regular expressions where `Jo*` will match `Jooooooooo` and not `John`, if I want to resolve this there will be a need to do `Jo.*` where `.` represents any character. @Alex Ott

Comment: Every system uses has it's own regex language. Here the Java's is used...