# Inconsistent highlighting in Solr

Tags: apache, solr

I have indexed data using Solr.I want to highlight matched keyword in search results. highlighting is inconsistent.
eg. if search keyword is 'alonso'.

highlighted instances are:
**Alonso**,fernando_**alonso**,***#Alonso***MeetVettel

non-highlightes instances are :
@fernandoalonso, www.alonsodriver.com

Can anyone tell me why is that?

I am using this configuration-

```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory and the WordDelimiterFilterFactory the words will be split on whitespace and underscore and then searchable. A word like fernandoalonso is not split in the same way by this TokenizerFactory. In order to get hits and highlights on fernandoalonso you have to use ngrams to make the whole word into lots of smaller words that are part of that word. Like nso, onso, lonso, alonso.

A good answer including the use of ngrams can be found at [Apache solr search part of the word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974394/apache-solr-search-part-of-the-word)